# Perl/TK window with no decoration moving with mouse

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have a Perl/Tk window which is displayed on top of all other windows.  It is a MainWindow->Frame->Label with text (it's a security classification banner).  It must be a window which is on top.  However, right now a user cannot move the window from its set location, so it will occasionally cover up a lower window control.

How can I make this window movable so it can be repositioned?

I don't have easy access to external modules since I'm on a closed network, so simple Perl/Tk code is best.

This is a Linux system running the KDE or Gnome desktop.

Comment: Can you add a minimal runnable example? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: I have found that if you remove the decorations from a Perl/TK mainwindow, it cannot then respond to mouse movements.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you remove the decorations from a Perl/TK mainwindow, it cannot then respond to mouse movements.

Comment: Please edit any extra details like this into your original question, or even the comments of the question.